# append dropdown value to url

Tags: javascript, html

I have managed to append the dropdown value to my url from the following element.

```
<label class="login_label" for="usertype">I am</label>
<select name="usertype" size="1" id="usertype" class="select1"> 
<option value="0" selected="selected">Staff</option>
<option value="1">Student</option>
<option value="2">Parent</option>
</select>
```

I have done this by appending ?usertype=1 to select student in the url. However, when the code looks like this: Almost similar, it can´t find a way to do it.

```
<label class="login_label">I am</label>
<div id="loginselect" style="clear:both:">
<select name="usertype" size="1" id="usertype" class="select1"> 
<option value="0" selected="selected">Staff</option>
<option value="1">Student</option>
<option value="2">Parent</option>
</select>
```

Can someone tell me how to enter the value 1 from the last code in the url? Or can´t it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, changing the `<form>` `action` attribute to `get` should solve this.

Comment: I forgot to mention, it´s not my website. I can´t modify the html. I just want to be able to link to http://www.nothing.com/Login.jsp?usertype=1 so that the choice of the dropdown is already set to student.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to parse url of the page

```
function getParam ( sname )
{
  var params = location.search.substr(location.search.indexOf("?")+1);
  var sval = "";
  params = params.split("&");
    // split param and value into individual pieces
    for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++)
       {
         temp = params[i].split("=");
         if ( [temp[0]] == sname ) { sval = temp[1]; }
       }
  return sval;
}
```

Then just set value of select to parameter from url

```
document.getElementById('usertype').value = getParam('usertype');
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, it´s not my website. I can´t modify the html. I just want to be able to link to http://www.nothing.com/Login.jsp?usertype=1 so that the choice of the dropdown is already set to student.